# Computer LCD, multiple white spots

Tags: display, lcd

Does anyone know of a resource for causes of different types of LCD monitor defects? I'd like to know what's causing a seemingly random spread of white dots (at least over 50, more than multiple pixel bulbs in size) to randomly appear and disappear on my screen.

Bonus points if there's a solution! But really, googling around for this information just isn't working out at all.

Comment: What kid of white dots?  A block of white pixels?  Is the pattern the same every time?  How long does it stay?  How long between appearances?

Comment: The appearance frequency is random but happens probably 5 times per 8 hour day. I think it may be related to what is on the display, but haven't had any luck testing that. It looks like a bunch of stars in the sky, bigger than 1 pixel each.

Comment: Is this not stuck pixels?

Comment: Can you add a photo showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First off, if this is a work computer (you mentioned 8 hour days), see your IT Helpdesk.

To rule out software:

- Try booting into a [Live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) ([list](http://www.livecdlist.com/)) and perform different tasks.  Note if the dots occur in any certain situations.  If the dots never occur on the Live CD, then software is most likely to blame.
- Try re-installing Windows, trying a different hard drive in the machine.
- Try to isolate the issue, to see if it occurs only when certain software is running.

To rule out hardware:

- Swap parts to isolate malfunctioning equipment (Video card, RAM, Motherboard, etc)
- Test your RAM ([Memtest 86](http://www.memtest.org/))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flashing colors on the screen? Sometimes this can solve the issue, try this youtube link as a test:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTmS-hKzwQ0

That doesn't work?

you could turn off your computer, apply pressure on the white dot area (start with 1) then turn on the computer so the screen flickers with colors, this may dislodge it also.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is a backlight issue with the screen? That generally as far as I have seen is what causes the white dots to show. Do you know what backlight type (LED, CFL, etc) the screen is?

Comment: Backlight issues would cause a dimming or over-brightened appearance distributed through one region.